# Testing for locale existence in Vimscript

Tags: vim

One of my problems when creating a portable `.vimrc` is with locales. Let's say I always want to use English language for messages. Depending on OS and Vim version, the command needed may be `lang messages en`, `lang messages en_US`, `lang messages English_US`, etc. Now, I can do this:

```
try
  lang messages en
catch
  try
    lang messages en_US
  catch
    try
      lang messages English_US
    catch
      ...
    endtry
  endtry
endtry
```

but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the vim help, you can use `let $LANG="en"`, so at least the following works (note that `--cmd` is executed before vimrc):

```
vim --cmd 'let $LANG="en"'
```

, but this produces the following error:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

, so this works only for english language (since `C` locale is english).

You can also use execute:

```
for s:lang in ["en", "en_US", "en_US.UTF-8", "English_US"]
    try
        execute 'language messages '.s:lang
        break
    catch /^Vim(language):E197:/
        " Do nothing
    endtry
endfor
unlet s:lang
```

Comment: I like this clever use of `break`!